# Why is $\sum_{p^k, k\ge 2} \frac{\log p}{p^k}\ll \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Consider the sum $\sum_{p^k, k\ge 2} \frac{\log p}{p^k}$ which is over all primes $p$ and powers of $\ge 2$. Then how do we have $\sum_{p^k, k\ge 2} \frac{\log p}{p^k}\ll \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^2}$?

The LHS is $\log p/p^2 + \log p/p^3 + \cdots$ for each prime $p$, and the RHS is just $\log p/p^2$ for each prime $p$. So it doesn't really make sense to me that the LHS is bounded by the RHS. Could anyone explain why this holds?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes but the LHS has sums of additional positive terms, how can we bound the infinite sum of $\log p /p^k$ , $k\ge 2$ by just the first term $\log p / p^2$? $\sum_{k\ge 2} 1/p^k = \frac{1/p^2}{1-1/p} = 1/(p^2-p) > 1/p^2$ is this not true?

Comment: ah sorry, in that case use $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{c^k}=\frac{1}{c^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty c^{-k}=\frac 1{c^2}\frac{1}{1-1/c}$ for all $c>1$, which is less than a constant times $\frac 1{c^2}$. (Note that in number theory, $\ll$ is often used as "less than a constant times...").

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Okay I follow your reasoning. But we have to sum the infinite sum over all primes $p$ so it would be problematic if $c$ depends on $p$. What I mean is we have $\sum_{p} \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{p^k} = \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \frac{1}{1-1/c_p}$. I guess we can fix that issue here since $1/(1-1/p)=p/(p-1)$ is $<2$ so that we have the  $\sum_{p} \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{p^k} <\sum_p 2 \frac{1}{p^2}$

Comment: Yes as you note, the term $1/(1-1/p)$ is decreasing in $p$, so it’s not a problem! I encourage you to post your insights as an answer to your question here, that may be helpful to future readers.